# Не могу понять почему не работает алгоритм последовательного поиска

Tags: c

```
int lookup(char *word, char *array[])
{
     int i;
     for(i = 0; array[i] != NULL; i++)
        if((strcmp(word, array[i])) == 0)
             return i; 
     return -1;
 }
   
 int main()
 {
     char *flab[] = { 
         "actually",
         "just",
         "quite",
         "really",
         NULL
     };
     char *array[255];  
     int i;  
     scanf("%s", array[255]);
     i = lookup(*flab, &array[255]);
     if(i == -1) {
         return 0;
     }   
     printf("%d", i);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
char *array[255];  
int i;  
scanf("%s", array[255]);
i = lookup(*flab, &array[255]);
```

на

```
char array[255];  
scanf("%s", array);
int i = lookup(array, flab);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i = lookup(*flab, &array[255]);
```

и

```
int lookup(char *word, char *array[])
```

ничего местами не перепутали?

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, то их можно задать с помощью кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Также, чтобы привлечь больше внимания к вопросу, можно [объявить награду](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/535772)

Comment: @Vanyamba Electronics, уверены? приведены 2 строчки кода из которых однозначно видно, что параметры перепутаны местами, о чем также сообщено автору в вопросительной форме